# QNetworkReply doesn't get JavaScript hidden in HTML Comment

Tags: javascript, html, qt, qtnetwork

I am using Qt 4.8 to make a HTTP Post Request.

```
void post() {
    QByteArray parameters;
    QUrl url("http://www.somerandomurl.com");

    QNetworkRequest request(url);
    request.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentTypeHeader, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

    QNetworkReply* reply = network_access_manager->post(request, parameters);
}

void requestfinished(QNetworkReply* reply) {
    QString response(QString::fromUtf8(reply->readAll()));
    std::cout << response.toStdString() << std::endl;
}
```

The HTML Page I should get, has Javascript hidden in an HTML comment. if I look at it with Firefox/Chrome or make a HTTP Request with Python3 I get the comment with the Javascript Code exactly the way I want it. Which looks like this:

```
<script language="JavaScript">
<!--
Javascript Code
Javascript Code
Javascript Code
//-->
</script>
```

With the Qt example however I only get the comment without the Javascript.

```
<script language="JavaScript">
<!--
//-->
</script>
```

Is there a way to get the Javascript as well with Qt 4.8?

Answer (score 2):

To me it seems highly unlikely that this is caused by Qt filtering JavaScript, but more likely by something on the server doing something based on the user agent. Try calling `request.setRawHeader("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/32.0.1667.0 Safari/537.36");` before you send off your request.

Also your request looks a little strange. You're POSTing with Content-type "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" but not providing any data. Why not just GET the URL?

Also, if you can share the URL, it would be easier to debug. Of course, if it's not possible, that's ok too.